# Can not prevent submit form in angular js ?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I try many solutions to prevent my form submit after validataion by using

```
ng-submit="login_form.$valid"
```

But it still submit.
This is my code. 
http://codepen.io/ryantran/pen/bgWXjy

Comment: How is your form even getting submitted?  Are you using a function in your controller for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have defined action and method on your form, no matter what you do in angular it will submit.

If you want to handle the validation with angular you have to remove those and use $http or $resource to make your server call in your submit method.

Comment: Link to the relevant documentation ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action

Answer (score -1):

ng-submit takes a function to call, when you click on submit button. the way you are using will not work. To make it work, you can use it like:

```
  <form name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="loginForm.$valid ? login() : ''">
```

Using **loginForm.$valid ? login() : ''"** this condition makes sure that your function will only be called when form is valid.

And in controller:

```
 $scope.login = function () {
    if ($scope.loginForm.$valid) { //don't need to check validation here again because condition in ng-submit is doing this for you, only to show.
    authService.login(params).then(function(response) {
          //do what ever you want to, with you response
        }, function(error) {
           // do something
            }
        });
    }
```

make your all http request in service. Make sure $http is injected.
In authService make function like below:

```
this.login = function (params) {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: serviceURI.loginURI,
            data: params,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };
```

serviceURI is where i save all api urls as a constant.